# closest in jQuery with class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.12.4 to set get the value of the closest preceding element using class selector. I'm unable to select the closest element.

```js
$(function() {
  $("[class='quickSelect']").blur(function() {
    var obj = $(this);
    alert($(this).parent());
    // alert($(this).closest("[class~='endDateField']"));  
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">
      Start Date
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="debitStartDate" value="" class="dateField startDateField">
    </td>
    <td align="right">
      End Date
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="debitEndDate" value="" class="dateField endDateField">
    </td>


    <td class="debitApportioner" style="align:right">
      Quick Select
    </td>
    <td class="debitApportioner" colspan="2">
      <select class="quickSelect">
          <option> SELECT  </option>
          <option> JANUARY  </option>
          <option> FEBRUARY  </option>
          <option> MARCH  </option>
      </select>
      <input class="quickSelect" type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: `.closest("[class~='startDateField']")` why not `.closest(".startDateField")`? would be a lot more efficient but think you need to read up on closest - it traverses up the tree, not up sideways and down

Comment: why not use `$(".quickSelect)` ? the dot selector means class

Comment: `closest` looks for ancesters, not siblings

Comment: Where's `endDateField` in your code snippet?

Comment: @Pete I think that's the issue. How to traverse to the immediate parent and find .startDateField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(".quickSelect").blur(function() {
    var obj = $(this);
    obj.closest('tr').find('.endDateField');  // will find the endDateField in the current row
  });
```

`closest()` only traverses up the trees ancestors and stops at the first element that matches the selector so the above says find the closest ancestor `tr` to the input then find any `endDateField` inside that tr

Comment: Minimum requirement from +25k users, provide an explanation!

Comment: @LGSon there is a comment next to the line to explain what it was doing and I was in the middle of typing an explanation, bit of patience please

Comment: The comment doesn't explain why...the edit does :) ... and regarding patience, don't be faster than provide a good answer from start

Comment: @Ele not eager for rep - as you can see I don't need anymore - I have full access to everything I want - it's just the way I answer questions get code in first then add comments to pad it out, saves me from switching between snippet view all the time and stops me from accidentally losing the code as I have refreshed the page on many ocasion by mistake